# Couchbase 3.1.0 - Hard out of memory error when performing full backup

Tags: backup, couchbase

We recently migrated to Couchbase 3.1.0. The odd thing is - when performing full backup of a bucket, web UI alerts "Hard Out Of Memory Error. Bucket X on node Y is full. All memory allocated to this bucket is used for metadata". The numbers from RAM usage in the web UI contradict that - about 75% is used, but not 100%. I looked into the logs, but haven't find any similar errors there.
Is that even normal?

Comment: Are you doing a global backup of the cluster from a single machine, a per-node backup, or a direct backup from the data files?

Comment: @DavidOstrovsky I back up single bucket from an entire cluster

Comment: @DavidOstrovsky any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in the Couchbase Server 3.x releases.

To understand the problem, we must also first understand Database Change Protocol (DCP), the protocol used to transfer data throughout the system. At a high level the flow-control for DCP is as follows:

1. The Consumer creates a connection with the Producer and sends an Open Connection message. The Consumer then sends a Control message to indicate per stream flow control. This messages will contain “stream_buffer_size” in the key section and the buffer size the Consumer would like each stream to have in the value section.
2. The Consumer will then start opening streams so that is can receive data from the server.
3. The Producer will then continue to send data for the stream that has buffer space available until it reaches the maximum send size.
4. Steps 1-3 continue until the connection is closed, as the Consumer continues to consume items from the stream.

The `cbbackup` utility does not implement any flow control (data buffer limits) however, and it will try to stream all vbuckets from all nodes at once, with no cap on the buffer size. 
While this does not mean that it will use the same amount of memory as your overall data size (as the streams are being drained slowly by the cbbackup process), it does mean that a large memory overhead is required to be able to store the data streams. 
When you are in a heavy DGM (disk greater than memory) scenario, the amount of memory required to store the streams is likely to grow more rapidly than cbbackup can drain them as it is streaming large quantities of data off of disk, leading to very large streams, which take up a lot of memory as previously mentioned.

The slightly misleading message about metadata taking up all of the memory is displayed as there is no memory left for the data, so all of the remaining memory is allocated to the metadata, which when using value eviction cannot be ejected from memory.

The reason that this only affects Couchbase Server versions prior to 4.0 is that in 4.0 a server-side improvement to DCP stream management was made that allows the pausing of DCP streams to keep the memory footprint down, this is tracked as [MB-12179](https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/MB-12179). 
As a result, you should not experience the same issue on Couchbase Server versions 4.x+, regardless of how DGM your bucket is.

#### Workaround

If you find yourself in a situation where this issue is occurring, then terminating the backup job should release all of the memory consumed by the streams immediately. 
Unfortunately if you have already had most of your data evicted from memory as a result of the backup, then you will have to retrieve a large quantity of data off of disk instead of RAM for a small period of time, which is likely to increase your get latencies. 
Over time 'hot' data will be brought into memory when requested, so this will only be a problem for a small period of time, however this is still a fairly undesirable situation to be in.

The workaround to avoid this issue completely is to only stream a small number of vbuckets at once when performing the backup, as opposed to all vbuckets which cbbackup does by default.

This can be achieved using `cbbackupwrapper` which comes bundled with all Couchbase Server releases 3.1.0 and later, details of using `cbbackupwrapper` can be found in [the Couchbase Server documentation](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.1/backup-restore/cbbackup-wrapper.html).
In particular the parameter to pay attention to is the `-n` flag, which specifies the number of vbuckets to be backed up in a batch at once. 
As the name suggests, `cbbackupwrapper` is simply a wrapper script on top of `cbbackup` which partitions the vbuckets up and automatically handles all of the directory creation and backup generation, while still using cbbackup under the hood. 
As an example, with a batch size of 50, cbbackupwrapper would backup vbuckets 0-49 first, followed by 50-99, then 100-149 etc.

It is suggested that you test with cbbackupwrapper in a testing environment which mirrors your production environment to find a suitable value for `-n` and `-P` (which controls how many backup processes run at once, the combination of these two controls the amount of memory pressure caused by backup as well as the overall speed). 
You should not find that lowering the value of `-n` from its default 100 decreases the backup speed, in some cases you may find that the backup speed actually increases due to the fact that there is far less memory pressure on the server. 
You may however wish to sensibly adjust the `-P` parameter if you wish to speed up the backup further.

Below is an example command:

`cbbackupwrapper http://[host]:8091 [backup_dir] -u [user_name] -p [password] -n 50`

It should be noted that if you use `cbbackupwrapper` to perform your backup then you must also use `cbrestorewrapper` to restore the data, as `cbrestorewrapper` is automatically aware of the directory structures used by `cbbackupwrapper`.

Answer (score 0):

When you run a full backup, by default the backup tool streams data from all nodes over the network. This is not the best way, because it causes a lot of extra load and increased memory usage, especially of you run cbbackup on one of the Couchbase nodes. I would use the data-copy mode of cbbackup, which copies data directly from the files on disk:

```
> sudo /opt/couchbase/bin/cbbackup couchstore-files:///opt/couchbase/var/lib/couchbase/data/ /tmp/backup
```

Of course, change the data path to wherever your Couchbase data is actually stored. (In my example it runs as sudo because only root has read access to /opt/couchbase/blabla..) Do this on every node, then collect all the backup folders and put them somewhere. Note that the backups are very compressible, so you might want to zip them before copying over the network.

Comment: ok, will try that. but my approach worked fine in 2.5.1 - before the upgrade

Comment: also, forgot to mention - the machine I run the backup tool from is not one of the cluster nodes, it just has Couchbase Server installed. and we use Windows

Comment: the reason I used cbbackup is because some of our buckets is quite big, I was hoping to utilise differential backups